# Not receiving emails from blocked e-commerce sites

Tags: email

Ubuntu blocks two of my e-mail sites that have to do with building a computer. I guess that means I'll be stuck with Secure Boot or another distro. These are not porn sites they are newegg.com and tomshardware.com. And I can't even ask why gwibber doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is not Ubuntu which is blocking you, it's Thunderbird. Also you can ask another question about gwibber.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't block sites; not those two, not porn sites, not sites for hate groups, nothing--there is no website-blocking mechanism installed by default in Ubuntu. (You could set it up to do so, but it would require substantial effort from you--you would know you'd done it.) We'll need more information, to be able to help you. Why do you assume Ubuntu is to blame? Are you unable to load *websites*, or is the problem *emails*? If the problem is that email is being wrongly classified as spam, and appearing in your spam folder, please provide more information about your email service.

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a question here, just ranting.  If you have a *real* question please [ask again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and try to be descriptive.  This question will be closed soon.  Thanks!

Comment: @Seth This is an *attempt* to ask a question; it is *not* just a rant. However, it is unclear *what* it is asking, and I cannot think of anything it could be asking that wouldn't require much more information, in order for an answer to be attempted. So it should probably be closed, but if it's edited for clarity, it can then be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry but those 2 sites sites and others work perfectly in Ubuntu. I am pretty sure they will work in all versions of Ubuntu that have ever existed. If you have those 2 sites blocked then you might have one or several of this issues (Try to remember if you or somebody did something to the computer, router or anything related to this issue):

- You or somebody has listed this sites as blocked in the Firewall or any other app that manages connection to sites.
- You or somebody has listed this sites in the web browser /email client / app as blocked.
- You have a router in between and it has been configured to block this sites
- If you are behind a proxy or using squid3 (Or similar apps) and they are listed as blocked.
- Your ISP has some very weird problems with this sites
- Any other network, security or configuration related issues that could end with this 2 sites being blocked.

So I would strongly suggest to first check (Starting with any Ubuntu configuration you might have edited and forgot or somebody else did) configurations in Ubuntu, then move from there to the router, proxy and start checking each one in regards to this 2 sites.

If you have another computer on your room/home/office, check with that one to cross from the list where the problem exists. If the other computer, using the same connection has the same issue, it might be the router, ISP or anything that offers the internet service to this computers. If the problem does not appear, then it might be a configuration problem done to Ubuntu.

What I am trying to say with this is that I am 99.99999% sure that this is not the fault of Ubuntu but misconfiguration, hardware related like router, servers and other issues between you and the sites. Use the information I provided in [Certain web pages load slowly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249229/certain-web-pages-load-slowly/249268#249268) to help you with your checking.